# OpenCV - How do I get started?

Tags: c++, c, windows, opencv, codeblocks

I just don't seem to be able to get OpenCV to work properly. Here's what I want to accomplish:

Use CodeBlocks (which I installed using codeblocks-10.05mingw-setup.exe) with OpenCV (installer: OpenCV-2.4.2.exe) on my Windows x64.

I've tried a lot of different configurations which will only bother you if I posted them all, so I hope you don't mind if I just ask the simple question: how do I get this to work?

I think I'm missing the smallest detail right now, so a detailed description of how to get started would be welcome.

Comment: The combination between CodeBlocks and Mingw on Windows is a troublemaker. Why not just switch to Visual Studio? It offers a free version. This way, you'll enjoy the many tutorials and SO answers about OpenCV config and startup

Answer (score 2):

If the OpenCV installer did the job, you should have by now OpenCV libraries and headers already installed in your system.

I would then go ahead and try to compile a hello world basic code, like the one you can get from [**here**](http://www.cs.iit.edu/~agam/cs512/lect-notes/opencv-intro/). If you would like to program using an IDE, like VisualC++ in Windows, you can follow [**this guide**](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VisualC++_VS2010) that will help you setting up the environment.

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV team just introduced their new [web site](http://opencv.org). There you can find [Introduction to OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/table_of_content_introduction/table_of_content_introduction.html#table-of-content-introduction) section with installation instructions, including detailed [instructions for Windows](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#windows-installation). Don't forget to cleanup your system before installation to avoid problems with mixing different install options. If you still can't get it working with CodeBlocks, follow Dan's advice and try compiling from command line.

When you are done with installation, go on and read there great new [tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html)!